# Compare 40ish statements without writing out each one?

Tags: php

I have to write up a statement that will let me compare versions of something and return a specific letter/number. At the moment the version being passed is in the correct format (EX: if its version 14 its being passed to me as version D, which is what would need to be returned) but I also need to check to see if its not ANY of these 40ish results.

For instance if I get passed a 99999 as a version that's not in our range of Versions we need to return, so I would have to return just an X. Is there an easy way to do this without needing to write out 40 if statements or switch cases?

Comment: Could you use something like: if(!in_array( $response, $arrResponses )) { return 'X'; } where $response is from the check for 'D' and $arrResponses is the list of known responses you allow for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an array for this easily.

```
$versions = array(
    14 => 'D',
    15 => '...',
    ...
);
if(!isset($versions[$input])) {
    $version = 'X';
}
else {
    $version = $versions[$input];
}

return $version; // Or whatever you need to do
```

Comment: snap - here, return the X requested?

Comment: Ah, yeah, I glossed over the 'X' bit. Fixing.

Comment: I suppose it would be good to know if the conditions are any complicated than this from the original question as it seems too obvious.

Comment: it is as simple as that. basically we have a version that is either 0-9 or a-z and if its not any of those it should just return as X. However I was hoping to find some way to do it without needing to write out all 40 options, however it seems like there's no way to do it without writing it all out. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: If the options are sequential (or have an algorithm for how they're generated) you could programmatically generate them. E.g., `for($i = 10, $j = 'A'; $i <= 50; $i++, $j++) { $versions[$i] = $j; }`. Otherwise, you're probably out of luck in that regard.